# Power analysis for GLS / OLS Generalized Least Squares

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, generalized-least-squares

I would like to perform a GLS model to test the effect of several physiological predictors (as covariates) on another physiological trait, in primates.

Because the time window between 2 consecutive collections of the physiological response can introduce some noise (2 samples collected close in time are more similar than 2 samples far in time), I'd like to use GLS which allows checking for auto-correlation.

However, I want to be sure I have a sample size big enough, and I would like to perform some power analysis on my GLS models but I found nothing online.

Any idea how to perform **power analyses on GLS**?